# Unable to instantiate activity на проекте после обновления плагина

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle

Решил вернуться к давно заброшенному проекту. Есть две копии проекта. В одном я обновил Android Gradle Plugin до 3.1.3 версии . После этого пришлось везде compile на implementation заменить. Но при запуске проекта на эмуляторе с апи 16, или 19 выпадает данное исключение. На эмуляторе с  апи 27 например, работает без проблем. 
Если же я весь проект переключу на апи 27 и добьюсь того, чтобы никаких ошибок и подсвечиваний кода с подсказками не останется, то ничего не меняется. 
Очистку проекта я проводил, приложение с эмулятора удалял и ставил по новой. *Instant run* у меня вроде итак в некликабельном состоянии.

Старый же проект, где Gradle не обновлен и везде еще compile стоит, работает на всех апи, но без звука.

Пока писал, нашел зацепку для себя: в манифесте какой то

```
 android:name = ".MyApplication"
```

Я проект писал когда еще ООП не знал как расшифровывается, так что понятия не имею из каких соображений мог это написать. Синглтон я не использую (но собираюсь, для доступа к классу с воспроизведением музыки из разных активностей)  В общем без этой строки приложение запускается, но без звука, так что прикладываю и класс в котором статический MediaPlayer запускается (и вообще ведь можно MediaPlayer сделать статик и не использовать синглтон?)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.igeniy"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/fonts', 'src/main/res/raw'] }
    }
    dependencies {
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:percent:25.4.0'
        //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'

    }
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':vksdk_library')
    }
    compileOptions {
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{example.igeniy/example.igeniy.SplashScreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.igeniy.SplashScreen

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name = ".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".StartActivity"/>

    <activity android:name=".Menu"/>

    <activity android:name=".RecordList"/>

</application>
```

В этом классе нет `setContentView(R.layout.activity);`   но вроде из-за этого ошибка не появлялась, а просто робот на синем фоне отображался)

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean flag;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate (@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.acdc);
            mediaPlayer.start();

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
            }
            flag = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, StartActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
         protected void onRestart() {
             finish();
             super.onRestart();

         }

}
```

Comment: Проверьте совпадают ли имена пакетов, в которых лежат классы, прописанные в манифесте, с атрибутом `package`, если нет - измените атрибут (если пакет один), или пропишите имена полностью (`pacage.name.ClassName`). `android:name = ".MyApplication" ` - если у Вас нет такого класса нужно убрать. И настроить multydex согласно документации: [Configure your app for multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle), если у Вас реально куча библиотек или отключить его, если не нужен

Comment: @woesss, с пакетами и классами был порядок. Просто отключил multidex и приложение стало запускаться и на меньших апи. Я его подключал когда пытался гуглСервисы подключать, вот тогда ругалось что библиотек много, единственное что я сделал написал multiDexEnabled true  и всё работало, до обновления gradle. А так библиотек  на пальцах посчитать можно.

Comment: Причина отсутствия звука была в том, что на эмуляторе что то погибло и при отключении эмулятора делается снимок системы, чтобы быстрее запустить его в след раз и эта ошибка сохранялась. Просто выкл и вкл эмулятор и звук появился.